# angular: how to use $scope with variable?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I'm beginner in angular. I'm using $http to get JSON data from the server by clicking on a button. my end goal is to fill all my HTML input forms with the server returning data automatically. I'm trying to do this with a forEach loop:

```
$http.post("check_ad", postData, config).then(function (response) {
    angular.forEach(response.data.getValue, function(value, key) {
        $scope.key = value;
    });
});
```

My HTML is:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="test">
<input type="text" ng-model="test2">
```

The server returning data is:

```
{"getValue":{"test":"hello","test2":"world"}}
```

My problem is that "key" variable is not working for me. If I'm trying to go direct without the "key" it's working OK:

```
$http.post("check_ad", postData, config).then(function (response) {
    angular.forEach(response.data.getValue, function(value, key) {
        $scope.test = value;
        $scope.test2 = value;
    });
});
```

My question is how i'm using $scope with variable?
And another question is if there is a better way to do that Instead using forEach?

Thanks you :)

Comment: `$scope[key] = value`

Comment: So easy! Thanks Phil!!!